# Get top two records for each product

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with three fields as below, each product has multiple records. I'm wondering how can I fetch top 2 for each product? I sorted my records by time field already.

```
eventId productId   time
1       10568       2011-08-30 15:06:57
2       10568       2011-08-30 15:06:56
3       10568       2011-08-30 15:06:53
4       10568       2011-08-30 15:06:50

5       10111       2011-08-30 15:06:56
6       10111       2011-08-30 15:06:53
7       10111       2011-08-30 15:06:50

8       10000       2011-08-30 15:06:56
9       10000       2011-08-30 15:06:53
10      10000       2011-08-30 15:06:50
```

Can any expert help me to get top 2 records for EACH product?

Comment: Follow the `greatest-n-per-group` tag.  This question has been answered dozens of times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: [greatest-n-per-group + mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql?sort=votes&pagesize=50)

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from table t 
inner join (select distinct productId as productId from table) table2 
  on (table2.productid = t.productid
where table.time >= (select time from table innertable 
                     where productid = t.productid 
                     order by time desc 
                     limit 1 offset 1)
```

Comment: I guess Limit 2 gets the first 2 of the group, without offset

Comment: Good query, but it will exclude products with only a single event. Which is solvable by adding OR with the same sub-select, but with limit 1, without offset. And I also fixed a small typo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an SQL editor at hand, but it could probably look like this :

```
SELECT * FROM theTable WHERE eventId IN 
    (SELECT TOP(2) eventId FROM theTable as innerTable 
        WHERE innerTable.productId = theTable.productId)
```

Replace "theTable" with your table name.

Comment: TOP is for SQLSERVER, MYSQL uses LIMIT

Comment: yep, and you have to do WHERE ROWNUM <= 2 in Oracle. Such a commonly used feature, I'm surprised there isn't one single standard way...